# How to create an Azure Kusto query to group by client OS name only (OS version removed) on App insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

**What I want**

The number of page views grouped by client OS (no OS version = only OS name) and week.

**What I have** - Kusto query:

```
pageViews
|where timestamp > ago(90d)
|summarize Browser_hits = count() by Date = startofweek(timestamp), client_Browser
|sort by Date   
|render timechart
```

The problem with this query is that the client OS name is coming with the version in it and that ends up in different versions grouping separately (see picture below).

[image]

**Update**

This is close to what I need but it won't work for any names, I'm just posting this as an example that helps to understand the actual question.

```
pageViews
|where timestamp > ago(90d)
|summarize Browser_hits = count() by Date = startofweek(timestamp), BrowserNameTrimed = substring(client_Browser,0,5)
| sort by Date   
| render timechart
```

With the previous query I get this (kind of cheating):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

would this work? (parsing the browser name out of the "browser name + browser version" combination using the `parse` operator):

```
pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| summarize Browser_hits = count() by Date = startofweek(timestamp), client_Browser
| parse kind=regex client_Browser with client_Browser @" \d+" *
| render timechart
```